# API or get data from google page insight

Tags: php, google-api

I am looking to fetch data like from this https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ is there any api or any other data fetching technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the api for getting the data from page insight. Please follow the link.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v2/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed#response